# Не запускается код в Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не запускается даже обычный начальный код от Visual Studio, в чем проблема

Comment: Что-то вы не так настроили — он у вас заголовочные файлы не видит..

Comment: Честно, даже в настройках не ползал, установил изначально что просило и всё, пользуюсь VS 1 раз

Comment: я бы дал совет - не увлекайтесь вы локализацией... все эти "Средства", "Окно" и т.п. - выглядяд очень чужеродно, особенно учитывая, что основная документация - на английском. А по вопросу: удалитть - установить заново пробовали?

Comment: да,пробовал,ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что не установлен набор инструментов для программирования на С++. Проверить и установить их можно через окно-инсталлер студии: Tools -> Get Tools and Features...[image: Tools -> Get Tools and Features...]. Найдите и установите, если надо, Desktop Development with C++ [image: Desktop Development with C++]. Если набор установлен, но ошибка остаётся, то проверяйте, как создавали проект.